# Connecting to (an AWS hosted) Microsoft SQL Server through Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services, odbc, pyodbc

Does anyone have experience connecting to (an AWS hosted) Microsoft SQL Server through Linux using pyodbc?

This is my script:

```
    import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;PORT=1433;DATABASE=action_plan_db;UID=myuserid;PWD=mypassword;TDS_Version=7.0')
```

I am getting the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'
```

I have seen that it has been recommended to Setup unixODBC to use FreeTSD & add a data source which involves editing two files: the “drivers” and “system data source” (/etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini respectively). However, when I open these they are blank.

Answer (score 1):

What Linux distro are you on?

Here is a tutorial for Python + RHEL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python-rhel

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum update
sudo yum install python python-pip python-wheel python-devel
sudo yum group install "Development tools"
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-tools.repo
exit
sudo yum install msodbcsql
sudo yum install unixODBC-utf16-devel
pip install pyodbc
```